# IO callbacks on goroutine

Tags: go

I'm a beginner at golang. Looking at all golang tutorials, it looks you should create goroutines for everything. Coming from something like libuv in C where you can define callbacks for socket read/write on a single thread, is the right way to achieve that in golang to create nested goroutines for any IO tasks needed?

As an example, take something like nginx where a single thread will handle multiple connections. To do something like that in golang, we would need a goroutine for every connection?

Comment: "is the right way to achieve that in golang to create nested goroutines for any IO tasks needed?" No, of course not. Note that "any" leaves no room to answer with "yes" if even it is not the right thing to do for a single problem. What is your actual problem? The nginx example is missleading: The builtin webserver from net/http already does all this for you so you do not "**need** a goroutine for every connection" you already _have_ a goroutine for each request.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the design philosophy in golang. Let's say I'm building a proxy server from scratch, not using net/http but just net.Listen(). In nginx, one thread would multiplex over multiple connections, is that possible/recommended in golang. So my question is, Create a new goroutine for every connection and nested goroutines within that for any IO needed, or is there a different way to do it in go?

Comment: Create goroutines. Note that goroutines and threads are different things. Of course you can reimplement what nginx does in Go, but why would you? I doubt that investigating this particular problem and comparing it to a distinct solution won't yield much light on concurrency in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go stands out in the area of tools to write networked services specifically because of the fact it has I/O-awareness integrated right into the runtime scheduler powering any running GO program.

The basic idea is roughly like this: a goroutine performs normal, sequential, callback-free operations on sockets — that is, plain reads and plain writes, — and as soon as the next I/O operation would block (yes, the relevant syscall on a Unix-like kernel returns `EWOULDBLOCK`), the goroutine is suspended, its socket is handed out into a component of the runtime called "netpoller", which is implemented using the platform-native socket I/O multiplexor such as `epoll`, `kqueue` or IOCP, and the OS thread the goroutine was running on is handed off to another goroutine which wants to run. As soon as the netpoller signals the I/O on the socket caused the goroutine to suspend can proceed, the scheduler queues that goroutine for execution and then it contnues to run exactly where it left off.

Because of this, the usual model employed when writing networking services in Go is to have one goroutine per socket. When you're writing plain TCP server, you should create a goroutine yourself (and hand it the socket returned by the listener once it accepted a client's connection).
`net/http.Server` has this behaviour built-in as it creates a goroutine to serve each incoming client request (actually, for HTTP/1.x, two or even three goroutines are created per connection, but it's invisible to HTTP request handlers).

Now, we've just covered the basics. Of course, there might exist legitimate reasons to have extra goroutines to handle tasks needed to be carried out to complete a request, and that's what @Volker referred to.

More info:

- ["What color is your function?"](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) — a classical essay dealing with I/O multiplexing implemented as a library vs it being implemented in the core.
- ["Go's work-stealing scheduler"](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/); also see [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) and [this](https://morsmachine.dk/netpoller) and [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TTj4T2JO42uD5ID9e89oa0sLKhJYD0Y_kqxDv3I3XMw/).
- [State threads library](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) which implements the approach quite similar to that of Go, just on much lower level. Its documentation is quite insightful on the approach implemented in Go.
  [`libtask`](https://swtch.com/libtask/) is a much more recent stab at
  the same problem, by one of Go's creators.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!